# Problem with finding critical point of trig function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

> 2. Let $f(x)=x+\cot(x/2),\quad x\in\left[\frac\pi3,\frac{2\pi}3\right]$.
>
> (a) Find all the critical numbers in the domain.
>
> (b) Find the absolute maximum value and minimum value.
>
> Solution: (a) $$f'(x)=1-\frac1{2\sin^2(x/2)}=0,\Rightarrow\sin(x/2)=\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}$$
>
> It has only one solution $x=\frac\pi2$ in $\left[\frac\pi3,\frac{2\pi}3\right]$.
>
> (b) Note that $f\left(\frac\pi2\right)=\frac\pi2+1,f\left(\frac\pi3\right)=\frac\pi3+\sqrt3,f\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right)=\frac{2\pi}3+1/\sqrt3$. Therefore,
>
> Thus $f\left(\frac\pi3\right)=\frac\pi3+\sqrt3$ is the absolute maximum, $f\left(\frac\pi2\right)=\frac\pi2+1$ is the absolute minimum.

Can anyone help me out solving this? I don't understand how my professor ends up with 
$$
1 - \frac{1}{2\sin^2(x/2)}
$$

Comment: What is the derivative of $\cot(x)$?

Comment: -csc^2(X) i believe?

Comment: Which is the same as $-\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}$ ;)

Comment: Again, please type up your questions and don't just post a picture of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using quotient rule to differentiate $\cot(x) = \cos(x)/\sin(x)$ gives

$$
\cot'(x) = (-\sin(x)\sin(x) - \cos(x)\cos(x) )/\sin^2(x) = -1/\sin^2(x),
$$
 so if the argument is $x/2$ then by the chain rule we get
$$
\cot'(x/2) = -1/2\sin^2(x/2). 
$$

Comment: I edited your answer. Please use LaTeX (MathJax) to format questions and answers. You can find more about this here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference